# How can I go about adding a ProgressBar to this code which calculates CRC32 checksum in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, progress-bar, crc32

Thanks for reading - I am using the class below to calculate the CRC32 checksum of a specified file.

My question is how would I go about reporting the progress of file completion (in %) to a progressbar on a different form. I have tried (i / count) * 100 under the New() sub but I am not having any luck, or setting the progress bar with it for that matter. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Steve

```
Public Class CRC32

Private crc32Table() As Integer
Private Const BUFFER_SIZE As Integer = 1024

Public Function GetCrc32(ByRef stream As System.IO.Stream) As Integer

    Dim crc32Result As Integer
    crc32Result = &HFFFFFFFF

    Dim buffer(BUFFER_SIZE) As Byte
    Dim readSize As Integer = BUFFER_SIZE

    Dim count As Integer = stream.Read(buffer, 0, readSize)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim iLookup As Integer

    Do While (count > 0)
        For i = 0 To count - 1

            iLookup = (crc32Result And &HFF) Xor buffer(i)
            crc32Result = ((crc32Result And &HFFFFFF00) \ &H100) And &HFFFFFF
            crc32Result = crc32Result Xor crc32Table(iLookup)
        Next i


        count = stream.Read(buffer, 0, readSize)
    Loop

    GetCrc32 = Not (crc32Result)

End Function

Public Sub New()


    Dim dwPolynomial As Integer = &HEDB88320
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

    ReDim crc32Table(256)
    Dim dwCrc As Integer

    For i = 0 To 255
    Form1.CRCWorker.ReportProgress((i / 255) * 100)  'Report Progress
        dwCrc = i
        For j = 8 To 1 Step -1
            If (dwCrc And 1) Then
                dwCrc = ((dwCrc And &HFFFFFFFE) \ 2&) And &H7FFFFFFF
                dwCrc = dwCrc Xor dwPolynomial
            Else
                dwCrc = ((dwCrc And &HFFFFFFFE) \ 2&) And &H7FFFFFFF
            End If
        Next j

        crc32Table(i) = dwCrc
    Next i

    'file complete
End Sub

End Class
  '------------- END CRC32 CLASS--------------
   '-------------- START FORM1 --------------------------
Private Sub CRCWorker_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles CRCWorker.DoWork

 For i = CurrentInt To dgv.Rows.Count - 1
              CRCWorker.ReportProgress(0, i & "/" & Total_Files)
              Current_File_Num = (i + 1)
              SetControlText(lblCurrentFile, Str(Current_File_Num) & "/" & Total_Files)
              result = CheckFile(SFV_Parent_Directory & "\" & dgv.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value, dgv.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value)
           Select Case result
               Case 0 ' missing file
                   UpdateRow(i, 2, "MISSING")
                   'dgv.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = "MISSING"
                    Missing_Files = Missing_Files + 1
                    SetControlText(lblMissingFiles, Str(Missing_Files))
               Case 1 ' crc match
                    UpdateRow(i, 2, "OK")
                  ' dgv.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = "OK"
                    Good_Files = Good_Files + 1
                    SetControlText(lblGoodFiles, Str(Good_Files))
              Case 2 'crc bad
                    UpdateRow(i, 2, "BAD")
                    ' dgv.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = "BAD"
                    Bad_Files = Bad_Files + 1
                    SetControlText(lblBadFiles, Str(Bad_Files))
            End Select
            If CRCWorker.CancellationPending = True Then
                e.Cancel = True
                Exit Sub
            End If


      Next
       End Sub
    Private Sub CRCWorker_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles CRCWorker.ProgressChanged

    Dim val As Integer = e.ProgressPercentage
    ProgressBar2.Maximum = 100
    ProgressBar2.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
    Debug.Print(val)

    End Sub

     Function CheckFile(ByVal tocheck_filepath As String, ByVal expected_crc As String) As Integer 'returns result of a file check 0 = missing 1 = good 2 = bad

    If File.Exists(tocheck_filepath) = False Then
        Return 0 'return file missing
    End If
    Dim f As FileStream = New FileStream(tocheck_filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 8192)
    Dim c As New CRC32()

    crc = c.GetCrc32(f)
    Dim crcResult As String = "00000000"
    crcResult = String.Format("{0:X8}", crc) 
    f.Close()

End Function
```

Comment: Are you using WinForms, WPF, WebForms?

Comment: Hi There thanks for the reply, I am using WinForms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows Forms [BackgroundWorker Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) is often used to run intensive tasks in another thread and update progress bar without blocking the interface.
[Example](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/88605-the-background-worker/) of using BackgroundWorker in VB.Net

The problem is when you use use the form in your code without instantiating it `Form1.CRCWorker.ReportProgress((i / 255) * 100)` there is a kind of hidden "[auto-instantiation](http://visualbasic.about.com/od/quicktips/qt/formasclass.htm)" happening and new instance of `Form1` is created each time.

Comment: Sure, I am using a BackgroundWorker, but just to call the sub not actually containing it. Is the only way to do this to put use this code in it's own Background worker? Thanks.

Comment: Inside the DoWork event handler we do our task (call New and GetCrc32 method). At each iteration we call the ReportProgress method on the BackgroundWorker instance.

In the ProgressChanged event handler, we set the value of the ProgressBar to the ProgressPercentage property of the ProgressChangedEventArgs argument. This will be the values 1 through 100 sequentially.

Comment: Yeah, I am currently doing this, and I have it reporting progress of the file list using this method, however I wish to also report the progress of the file currently being checked (not the progress of the file list) and eventually the speed at which it is being read 3mb/s etc, as when it is checking a big file it looks like it is doing nothing. How would I go about this? Thanks.

Comment: If you want you can use [Marquee style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbarstyle). The progress bar in this case is rendered as a Marquee continuously moving without any intervention of the programmer and without indicating the quantity of progress.

Comment: Yes thank you. I know about these bits, my last comment describes my problem more. Thanks

Comment: If possible show us the code inside DoWork and also where you call ReportProgress and finally your form's ProgressChanged event handler.

Comment: Here is my DoWork section and you can see where report progress is called, ProgressChanged simply updates the progressbar value. However this is the progress of the list of files. I wish to get the % complete of the file currently being checked:

Comment: The first parameter in ReportProgress method is the _percentage, from 0 to 100_, of the background operation that is complete. Call it like this  `CRCWorker.ReportProgress(i & "/" & Total_Files, "Working...")`

Comment: And also if you want to report the progress of the file you need to call ReportProgress from within `CheckFile` method

Comment: Sure, I know all that, this is what I was asking. As CheckFile is in it's own sub, How do I called a ReportProgress from within there, I can only call it from DoWork.  Thanks

Comment: Hi, I did what you suggested and called the reportprogess from the CheckFile sub and it reports the correct current value using ProgressPercentage, This prints fine in the debug window however when I come to update the progressbar (Progressbar2.value = e.ProgressPercentage) It does not update the progress bar at all. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show us the code for the `CheckFile`? You can pass `CRCWorker` directly as a parameter or use events to callback into the form's code.

Comment: Did you set `Progressbar2.Maximum`? Do you call `Progressbar2.value = e.ProgressPercentage` from UI thread?

Comment: Hello, Yes, I set the maximum and called it like that. I have updated the code so you can see. I call the ReportProgress when the CRC32 class is called, the Debug.Print reports the value correctly, but if I set it to show in a label it doesn't show. If I also do progressbar1.value it shows the correct value but it does not update. I have also tried application.doevents() and progressbar2.update both do not work. Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Did you set [BackgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.workerreportsprogress.aspx) to **true**?

Comment: Yes :) That's why I am confused, Is it ok to call Form1.CRCWorker.ReportProgress ... from the Class? It prints fine with Debug.print but doesn't update the progress bar at all.. I don't get it..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15744/discussion-between-jacob-seleznev-and-nookster)

Answer (score 2):

It appears your .ReportProgress() call is in the New() subroutine, which is the part that makes the lookup table for the CRC calculation.  The New() subroutine is called once, before the main CRC routine.  The main CRC routine is the one that takes up all the time and needs the progress bar.

Shouldn't the progress bar updating be in the GetCrc32() function? Something like this:

```
    Public Function GetCrc32(ByRef stream As System.IO.Stream, _
                             Optional prbr As ProgressBar = Nothing) As UInteger
    Dim crc As UInteger = Not CUInt(0)
    Dim buffer(BUFFER_SIZE) As Byte
    Dim readSize As Integer = BUFFER_SIZE
    Dim left As Long = stream.Length
    If Not (prbr Is Nothing) Then ' ProgressBar setup for counting down amount left.
        prbr.Maximum = 100 
        prbr.Minimum = 0 
        prbr.Value = 100
    End If
    Dim count As Integer : Do
        count = stream.Read(buffer, 0, readSize)
        For i As Integer = 0 To count - 1
            crc = (crc >> 8) Xor tbl((crc And 255) Xor buffer(i))
        Next
        If Not (prbr Is Nothing) Then ' ProgressBar updated here
            left -= count 
            prbr.Value = CInt(left * 100 \ stream.Length)
            prbr.Refresh()
        End If
    Loop While count > 0
    Return Not crc
End Function
```

Comment: Just noticed your discussion room chat where you discovered the progressBar update needed to be in the GetCrc32() routine, but was still getting stuck.  It was getting stuck because the fraction calculation for the progressBar was based on the position of the loop iterator in the buffer instead of the position of the buffer in the stream.